# Kettle Get Files Names - listing files from a list of folder names

Tags: file, directory, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to something fairly simple: I have a first "Get File Names" step that generates a list of folder names and a second "Get File Names" step that should take the folder names from the first and list the files in that folder. However, I have trouble getting the second step to work.

Answer (score 1):

Example below 
[image]

Anyway it is not recursive. It just make what u described. Only files in second level directory.

If u need recursive just use JavaScript Step and Java API to get recursive list of files.